# How can I find out which files are run from the scheduler when starting Windows

Tags: c#

How can I find out which files are run from the scheduler when starting Windows.I look in the registry, but do not find what files are run from the task scheduler

Comment: Are you looking for the programs that windows start on boot, or the programs executed via schedule tasks?

Comment: @RobBos I means  programs executed via schedule tasks.

Comment: Whenever you're thinking "how do I find out information *about* the windows OS?", your first thought should always be WMI. And, indeed, there's a [`Win32_ScheduledJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-scheduledjob) class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the list of Scheduled Tasks you can use a NuGet package like [TaskScheduler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler). Source code [here](https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler).